# Homepage for a new store : There was no Home CMS page configured or found

Tags: magento2, theme, multistore, store-view

I've just created multiples 'Pro' stores like this one. The Mayotte store is already existing and working. The Mayotte pro is a new store based on the same website as the Mayotte one.

[image: old and new store]

But when I go to my new store homepage I'm getting the error :

> There was no Home CMS page configured or found.

Moreover this error is shown in the default magento Luma theme (while I guess I should have a custom theme like for the previous store).

If I go to the store specific view : Store >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Default Pages >> CMS Home Page

The homepage is well filled with the same value as for the other store and of course the cache is cleared and flushed.

I guess I just miss some kind of layout or template definition or configuration somewhere, but I don't really know anything about front in Magento 2.

EDIT : Now I have the good theme after adding into Content >> Design >> Configuration the missing theme. But the error remains.

Comment: Did you select Home page for new store in `Page in Websites` tab ?

Comment: @Pawan Indeed as I said in the issue. Notice In Content > Design > Configuration : I had no theme affected, so now I have the good theme template. But I still have the error no home CMS page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the CMS page selected in the configuration under `Default Pages` > `CMS Home Page` is actually assigned to the right storeview.

Go to `Content` > `Pages` and select the Home Page, click `Edit` from the dropdown menu on the right.
[image]

Now make sure it is either assigned to `All Store Views` or your specific new storeview.
[image]

Comment: I have this : Main Website
   Main Website Store
      Default Store View

But I guess it should be fine as all my other stores works fine with this configuration.